# Problem with the \path command, undefined control sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a logic scheme but I've got a problem with the command `\path` of the `tikzpicture` environment. I don't know why, but I cannot create connections between nodes. I tried every kind of command (`\path`, `\path{draw}`, `\draw`, `\path[->]`, etc.) but when I compile LateX says that it is an `Undefined control sequence`. See my code below.

If I comment the lines with `\path...` the code works fine, but obviously the boxes aren't linked by any arrows.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using Win7, MikTeX 2.9 64 bit with TeXnicCenter

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{report}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}

\begin{document}
[...]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\tikzstyle{block1} = [rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,
    text width=80mm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum width=80mm, 
    inner sep=2mm]
\tikzstyle{block2} = [rectangle, draw=red, thin, fill=red!20,
    text width=80mm, text centered, sharp corners, minimum width=60mm, inner sep=2mm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, -latex’,shorten >=0pt];
\matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
{
    % row 1
        \node [block1] (init) {
            \large{\lstinline$startup.m$}
            \footnotesize{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item geometry file name
                \item fluid and thermodynamic library settings
                \item \textit{``Error\_report.txt''} initialization
            \end{itemize}
            }
            }; \\
    % row 2
        \node [block1] (main) {
            \large{\lstinline$turbine_calculation_singlepoint.m$}
            \footnotesize{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item thermodynamic boundary conditions settings
                \item load geometry
            \end{itemize}
            }
            }; \\
    % row 3
        \node [block2] (turb_calc) {
            \large{\lstinline$turbine_calculation.m$}
            };  \\
    % row 4
        \node [block2] (1st_calc) {
            First stage calculation with \lstinline$stage_calculation.m$
            }; \\
    % row 5
};

\tikzstyle{every path}=[line];
\path   (init)      -- (main);
\path   (main)      -- (turb_calc);
\path   (turb_calc) -- (1st_calc);

\end{tikzpicture}

[...]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use the TikZ library called `decorations` instead of the one called `snakes`. Incidentally, since it seems you want to typeset MATLAB listings, allow me to recommend the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://github.com/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier/wiki) package.

Comment: when I pasted your code I got `-latex’` instead of `-latex'`, after putting the right tip it worked.

Comment: @dcmst Good catch.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The original code contained a `’` (`RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` in Unicode) instead of `'` (`APOSTROPHE` in Unicode) into

```
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, -latex’,shorten >=0pt];
```

With the correct tip the code compiles fine:

[image]